# nginx + multiple instance of fastcgi-mono-server = WebResource.axd error

Tags: mono, nginx, web-farm, webresource.axd, fastcgi-mono-server

I'm running nginx which does load balancing over several instances of fastcgi-mono-server4 configured upstream.

Apparently when a webresource link is handled by a different fastcgi-mono-server than the one which originally produced the link it returns a 404 error.

I have set a persistent machinekey as recommended for webfarms but the problem still remains.

Any idea what could be wrong?

If it makes any difference: the application is written with F#/WebSharper and we disabled the session state and the forms authentication.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think fastcgi-mono-server is meant to be run in multiple instances